# Is it possible to use TensorFlow without writing any Python?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a strong preference for C/C++ and would prefer not to touch Python in my projects.

Is it possible to do this with TensorFlow?  It seems to advertise itself as a C/C++ SDK but then it asks you to use pip for installation -- I am confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

Installation instruction with C is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c).